# How to access values in the "Object" of a map in Map<String, Object>?

Tags: apex

I got a method that returns a `Map<String, Object>`. Where `Object` represents a custom metadata record:

customMetadata.put('custom_data_info', caseMetaData);

It returns something like this if I run a `System.debug`:

```
custom_data_info=Case_Configuration__mdt:{Active__c=true, Type__c=order_payment, Description__c=Some random text}
```

I wish to get the values such as `Active__c` and `Type__c`
If I do `System.debug(myMap.get('custom_data_info'));`

I get

```
Case_Configuration__mdt:{Active__c=true, Type__c ...}
```

I can't do `myMap.get('custom_data_info).Active__c`

Whats the solution here? The reason I'm using `Object` instead of the specific Custom metadata is because my map also needs to include other stuff, eg a string/bool combo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code already knows that this is Custom Metadata Type (CMT), since `Case_Configuration__mdt:`, so you only need to cast `Object` to correct type.

```
Case_Configuration__mdt caseConfiguration = (Case_Configuration__mdt) myMap.get('custom_data_info);
Boolean isActive = caseConfiguration.Active__c;
```

You can also do it in one line if you need only one value:

```
Boolean isActive = (Case_Configuration__mdt) myMap.get('custom_data_info).Active__c;
```